# findIndex of a string

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to find the row of a cell in a specific column that coints the same data I am passing, it should be a string. Alredy tryied to use `getDysplayValue` in the definition of nomeVenditore, it dosn't work. I don't have any clue of what the error is about, the argument in the method findIndex is underlined with red.

```
var nomeVenditore = scadenziario.getRange(eRow,13).getValue();
var colonnaVenditore = 8 //for example

var arrayVenditori = pnl.getRange(5,colonnaVenditore,5,1).getValues();
var rigaVenditore = arrayVenditori.join().split(",").findIndex(nomeVenditore)+5;

pnl.getRange(1,1).setValue(rigaVenditore);
```

It always returns `-1 + 5 = 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `findIndex` returns `-1`. If it does, then start from row `5` otherwise start from `index+5`:

```
  var nomeVenditore = scadenziario.getRange(eRow,13).getValue();
  var colonnaVenditore = 8 //for example
  var arrayVenditori = pnl.getRange(5,colonnaVenditore,5,1).getValues();
  var index = arrayVenditori.join().split(",").findIndex(c=>c==nomeVenditore);
  var rigaVenditore = index == -1 ? 5 : index + 5;
  pnl.getRange(1,1).setValue(rigaVenditore);
```

I used [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for the comparison to make the code smaller:

```
var rigaVenditore = index==-1?5:index+5;
```

Comment: I added your code. The var nomeVeditore get the value from a cell that in the test case i am running has written Lorenzo. With your code the result is an error that says Loranzo is not a function. My onjly goal is to find in what Row Lorenzo is written in a set column in an other sheet

Comment: can you log the variables so we know what they contain? otherwise we are going to assume things which is not going to work. Add `console.log(rigaVenditore)` `console.log(index)` at the end of the script so we both know what exactly they return. @MatteoMarinari

Comment: The script is triggered by an event, the console.log() doesn't show me anything

Comment: See this answer on how to see the logs https://stackoverflow.com/a/65956142/11225291

Comment: The error is thrown before i declare those 2 variables, it doesn't show any log even in the execution

Comment: Solved, the issue was findIndex(c=>c==nomeVenditore) thanks