# How do you use Logger.log(e) with Google Forms? (Using the NEW Apps Script Editor)

Tags: google-apps-script, ide

In the legacy Apps Script Editor you could log e from Google Form submissions.
How is this done in the NEW Apps Script Editor?

```
function myFunction(e) {
  Logger.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To make sure we are on the same page:

If you are going to run a function like this in **any** editor you are going to get `null`:

[image]

because simply `e` is not defined and it is only returning data upon trigger executions of this function. But this function is executed by some events depending on the type of trigger you are using. Therefore, you are not going to see anything (that is not `null`) in the console if you manually execute this function.

### After the function is triggered by specific events:

In any editor again, you can go to the execution page to see the details of the execution. In the new editor, you go to **Executions**:

[image]

and you can see a list of all the executions of this particular function. For example, if your function is a simple `onEdit` trigger e.g. `onEdit(e)`, you will see this upon editing a cell in the spreadsheet:

[image]

You can also see the type of the execution, whether it was executed by the script (Editor) or by a trigger (Simple Trigger).

But anyway, trigger functions are not supposed to be executed manually. As the name suggests, trigger functions are triggered upon events. It wouldn't make sense to use a trigger function and need to manually execute it. It would be a regular function then.

Comment: The bit about Executions helped. I added e.values and can now see my values returning in the Executions log.